# Making counter work in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a beginner student with java and this is my first time using the programming language java in the netbeans IDE.

I have came up to this point where I made my application that will be used to make top trumps card:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b77C2.png

However the counter Jlabel named available points goes bellow 0 into negative numbers which I dont want, everything else works great!

**Here is my code for the counter:**

```
public class addingPointsUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
void availablePoints() {
    if(Integer.parseInt(availablePoints.getText()) >=0 && Integer.parseInt(availablePoints.getText()) <=50)
    {
    System.out.println("...");
    }
else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"You have no more available points");
         }
}
int pointsAvailable=50;
    int speed=0;
    int power=0;
    int focus=0;
    int agility=0;
    int defence=0;
    int attack=0;

public addingPointsUI() {
    initComponents();
}
```

**Here is the code for the speed plus button:**

```
if (speed < 10 ){

        speed = speed + 1 ;

        pointsAvailable = pointsAvailable - 1 ;

        availablePoints.setText(String.valueOf(pointsAvailable));

        speedPoints.setText(String.valueOf(speed));

         } else{

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have maxed out your Speed");
    }
}
```

#### **Here is the code for the speed minus button:**

```
if (speed > 0 ){

        speed = speed - 1;

        pointsAvailable = pointsAvailable +1;

        availablePoints.setText(String.valueOf(pointsAvailable));

        speedPoints.setText(String.valueOf(speed));

    }else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You cannot take anymore points from Speed");
    }
}
```

Please take in mind that I'm a beginner with using java I'm also new to this website.

Thank your for your kind replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you allow users to add any more points, you could check to make sure there are points available.

```
if (speed < 10 ) {
    if (pointAvaialable <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are out of available points");
        return;
    }

    speed = speed + 1 ;
    pointsAvailable = pointsAvailable - 1 ;
    availablePoints.setText(String.valueOf(pointsAvailable));
    speedPoints.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
} else {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have maxed out your Speed");
}
```

Comment: I'd reorganize the logic to test `pointsAvailable` first and to get rid of the `return` statement (which may not be appropriate). Something like `if (pointsAvailable > 0) { /* current logic */ } else { /* message about no points */ }`.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely an option. I personally prefer reducing the number of blocks and indentation levels by checking the return condition first. If the logic behind checking for greater than in the if block is easier to understand, then you are probably right.

Comment: I think it comes down to this: when the user is both out of points and maxed out on speed, which message should be displayed? I guess it's really up to OP as to what takes precedence.

Comment: Ahh I think I misunderstood your initial comment. I didn't consider that but good point.

Comment: I have added this to each + and - button and it works perfeclty 'if (pointAvaialable <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are out of available points");
        return;
    }'

Comment: Glad I could help